# Invoke a column twice with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I really appreciate any help with this matter :)
Am Working on a Report now and I had faced some troubles 
I have this Query and it work fine , now I want to add a coulmn that is already exist in the query(from the same table) , but this time  i'll change the condition of it , BTW the conditions in both of the 2 column are based on one other column 
like for example If I have this :

```
Select Price from ITM1 WHERE PriceList = '1'
```

and also this

```
Select Price from ITM1 WHERE PriceList = '10'
```

how I can write in the same query and let them display in two different column ?
I will put the Query here in case if some one can help me through it :
you can see THE Column Price & PriceList in the lower part of it ,Bolded. 
I just need to make the samething again but with a new coulmn name thats it.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `CASE` expression work in your example? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: 1st thanx 4 ur reply , 2nd , am still new in this , i had tried too much things b4 posting here , and always there is an error , if you can guide me with an example or method i'll be very thankful

Comment: You can't add a column with a where that way. You should use select case when Pricelist = 1 then pricelist end as 'Column1' and the same thing but with =10 as 'column2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) will give you what you want.  However, there are other changes that you can make to your query which would boost performance - but it's out of scope to the question.  I'm unclear as to what you're trying to do with the different "columns"  Please help explain.  **Else see @Dave.Gugg's answer which does just that.**

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode,
    T0.ItemName,
    T0.CardCode,
    T0.CodeBars,
    T2.UgpCode,
    T3.AltQty,
    T3.BaseQty,
    CASE 
        WHEN T4.Uomentry = - 1
            THEN T0.[BuyUnitMsr]
        ELSE t4.UomName
    END AS 'UoMName',
    T4.UomEntry,
    T0.U_CAT_CODE,
    T0.U_CAT_NAME,
    T1.CardName,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) dbo.PDN1.U_AC_QTY_ORDER
        FROM dbo.PDN1
        INNER JOIN dbo.OPDN ON dbo.PDN1.DocEntry = dbo.OPDN.DocEntry
        WHERE (dbo.PDN1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode)
            AND (dbo.OPDN.CardCode = T0.CardCode)
        ORDER BY dbo.OPDN.DocDate DESC
        ) AS OQuantity,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) PDN1_1.U_AC_QTY_BONUS
        FROM dbo.PDN1 AS PDN1_1
        INNER JOIN dbo.OPDN AS OPDN_1 ON PDN1_1.DocEntry = OPDN_1.DocEntry
        WHERE (PDN1_1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode)
            AND (OPDN_1.CardCode = T0.CardCode)
        ORDER BY OPDN_1.DocDate DESC
        ) AS BQuantity,
    ITM1.Price,
    T0.U_DISC_PER
FROM dbo.OITM AS T0
INNER JOIN dbo.OCRD AS T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
INNER JOIN dbo.OUGP AS T2 ON T0.UgpEntry = T2.UgpEntry
INNER JOIN dbo.UGP1 AS T3 ON T2.UgpEntry = T3.UgpEntry
INNER JOIN dbo.ITM1 ON T0.ItemCode = dbo.ITM1.ItemCode
    AND dbo.ITM1.PriceList IN ('1', '10')
LEFT JOIN dbo.OUOM AS T4 ON T3.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
WHERE (T0.Series = '65')
    AND (
        T4.UomEntry = 3
        OR T4.UomEntry = '-1'
        )
```

---

If you want a different column (this may perform better than two joins):

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode,
    T0.ItemName,
    T0.CardCode,
    T0.CodeBars,
    T2.UgpCode,
    T3.AltQty,
    T3.BaseQty,
    CASE 
        WHEN T4.Uomentry = - 1
            THEN T0.[BuyUnitMsr]
        ELSE t4.UomName
    END AS 'UoMName',
    T4.UomEntry,
    T0.U_CAT_CODE,
    T0.U_CAT_NAME,
    T1.CardName,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) dbo.PDN1.U_AC_QTY_ORDER
        FROM dbo.PDN1
        INNER JOIN dbo.OPDN ON dbo.PDN1.DocEntry = dbo.OPDN.DocEntry
        WHERE (dbo.PDN1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode)
            AND (dbo.OPDN.CardCode = T0.CardCode)
        ORDER BY dbo.OPDN.DocDate DESC
        ) AS OQuantity,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) PDN1_1.U_AC_QTY_BONUS
        FROM dbo.PDN1 AS PDN1_1
        INNER JOIN dbo.OPDN AS OPDN_1 ON PDN1_1.DocEntry = OPDN_1.DocEntry
        WHERE (PDN1_1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode)
            AND (OPDN_1.CardCode = T0.CardCode)
        ORDER BY OPDN_1.DocDate DESC
        ) AS BQuantity,
    CASE 
        WHEN ITM1.PriceList = '1' 
            THEN ITM1.Price
        ELSE '0'
    END AS Price1, 
    CASE 
        WHEN ITM1.PriceList = '10' 
            THEN ITM1.Price
        ELSE '0'
    END AS Price2, 
    T0.U_DISC_PER
FROM dbo.OITM AS T0
INNER JOIN dbo.OCRD AS T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
INNER JOIN dbo.OUGP AS T2 ON T0.UgpEntry = T2.UgpEntry
INNER JOIN dbo.UGP1 AS T3 ON T2.UgpEntry = T3.UgpEntry
INNER JOIN dbo.ITM1 ON T0.ItemCode = dbo.ITM1.ItemCode
    AND dbo.ITM1.PriceList IN ('1', '10')
LEFT JOIN dbo.OUOM AS T4 ON T3.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
WHERE (T0.Series = '65')
    AND (
        T4.UomEntry = 3
        OR T4.UomEntry = '-1'
        )
```

Comment: only one price is shown and the nother is shown as 0 , or the oppissite , IN REAL , PriceList= '10 , and PriceLit = '1' both of them have data stored on them , so each coulmn must show the price of it own ,  the other problem is there is some replication happening with the same ItemCode , but in each row with diffrent Value , am taking the query to use in Crestal Report ,   I am trying to fix that now , hope I can  do so b4 the end of day :)       thx all again for your help

Comment: Hello Dan Andrews , I just want to thank you again  U and everyone replied to this , U had saved me today with your quick response , and not getting Embarrass in front of my management and client ,  as I am Still fresh  in my 1st project that helped too much , the client asked for more changes which I had done from understanding the changes you had done to the Query , I would like to send this as a Private Message to You  but I don't think the site provide this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just join to the table a second time, but you will need to make the joins outer:

```
SELECT  T0.ItemCode ,
        T0.ItemName ,
        T0.CardCode ,
        T0.CodeBars ,
        T2.UgpCode ,
        T3.AltQty ,
        T3.BaseQty ,
        CASE WHEN T4.Uomentry = -1 THEN T0.[BuyUnitMsr]
             ELSE t4.UomName
        END AS 'UoMName' ,
        T4.UomEntry ,
        T0.U_CAT_CODE ,
        T0.U_CAT_NAME ,
        T1.CardName ,
        ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                    dbo.PDN1.U_AC_QTY_ORDER
          FROM      dbo.PDN1
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OPDN ON dbo.PDN1.DocEntry = dbo.OPDN.DocEntry
          WHERE     ( dbo.PDN1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )
                    AND ( dbo.OPDN.CardCode = T0.CardCode )
          ORDER BY  dbo.OPDN.DocDate DESC
        ) AS OQuantity ,
        ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                    PDN1_1.U_AC_QTY_BONUS
          FROM      dbo.PDN1 AS PDN1_1
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OPDN AS OPDN_1 ON PDN1_1.DocEntry = OPDN_1.DocEntry
          WHERE     ( PDN1_1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )
                    AND ( OPDN_1.CardCode = T0.CardCode )
          ORDER BY  OPDN_1.DocDate DESC
        ) AS BQuantity ,
        dbo.ITM1.Price ,
        ITM1Second.Price,
        T0.U_DISC_PER
FROM    dbo.OITM AS T0
        INNER JOIN dbo.OCRD AS T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
        INNER JOIN dbo.OUGP AS T2 ON T0.UgpEntry = T2.UgpEntry
        INNER JOIN dbo.UGP1 AS T3 ON T2.UgpEntry = T3.UgpEntry
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ITM1 ON T0.ItemCode = dbo.ITM1.ItemCode
                               AND dbo.ITM1.PriceList = '10'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ITM1 ITM1Second ON T0.ItemCode = ITM1Second.ItemCode
                               AND ITM1Second.PriceList = '1'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OUOM AS T4 ON T3.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
WHERE   ( T0.Series = '65' )
        AND ( T4.UomEntry = 3
              OR T4.UomEntry = '-1'
            )
```

Comment: I like Dan Andrew's answer better, this one will run significantly slower, and could give bad results.

Comment: It depends on what he's doing.  Your answer is correct depending how you read the question :)

Comment: Dear @Dave.Gugg I can't thank you enouth  no matter I try , U just saved my day , :)   I'll take this as a begin to start from for me  :) :)

Comment: Dear Dan Andrews thax so much 4 UR REPLY :)